# How to get date in a datetime format triggered by a submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, datetime

I am creating a daily report for my system. 
I have an input type text that when clicked, a `datepicker` will appear. Upon clicking the submit button, it will get the `date` from the database. But this field has `datetime` stored. How can I get the `date` from database?

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" required autocomplete="off" title="Choose Date" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Show Report">

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpatientservices WHERE date_format(dateTimeStart,'%Y-%m-%d') = '$date' AND status='Done'");
```

Comment: you need to get date from db and place those into datepicker is it so ?

Comment: I need to get the date from db(wherein it has stored datetime) and echo it in a form.

Comment: Before you go any further I would make a friendly suggestion to change your code from `mysql` to `pdo_mysql`. `mysql` has been deprecated and soon your code will stop functioning. [pdo_mysql documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: `dateTimeStart` is the field name in the db and `$date` value is derived from the datepicker textbox?

Comment: yes @kuya. and i need to echo it.

Comment: FYI in HTML 5 there is `<input type="date">` that automatically brings up a date-time picker with no need for jQuery UI.

Comment: Date and DateTime are tricky little rascals and they have to be handled very carefully.

Comment: `<input type="date">` doesn't function in the latest version of firefox (40.0.3) or in IE 11 (11.0.9600.17905). But it does work in Chrome @jonbaldie

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.

```html
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpatientservices WHERE dateTimeStart = '$date' AND status='Done'");
```

Thanks

Comment: This is my first try. And it did not worked. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: if your database field have value something like 2015-09-01 00:00:00 then query would be $date = '2015-09-01%' ; $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpatientservices WHERE dateTimeStart like '$date' AND status='Done'"); this working perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that the date formats stored in your database match the date format of the DatePicker.

Then, rewrite your query like this...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpatientservices WHERE dateTimeStart = '$date' AND status='Done'");
```

You can then echo either value to the page... `$date` or the value retrieved by your query.

**Note:** If your db field is `datetime` then it is storing data like `2015-09-12 00:00:00` and they may not match. The DatePicker may simply send `2015-09-12`

Again, please do yourself a favor and convert to `pdo_mydql` You'll be glad you did later on. `mysql` has been deprecated and you are wide open to sql injection attacks on your database.

`mysql` will soon stop being supported and your code will stop functioning completely.

**Reference**

[pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: Will do that @kuya. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql `date()` function to get the date.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpatientservices WHERE date(dateTimeStart) = date('$date') AND status='Done'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Relplase your query with below query this may be helpful to you.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpatientservices WHERE DATE(dateTimeStart) = '$date' AND status='Done'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all, we should avoid keeping the name 'date' in textfield. It's better to have different name to avoid some ambiguity.

Changing the name of textfield to 'SelectedDate'

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="SelectedDate" required autocomplete="off" title="Choose Date" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Show Report">

In Table, dateTimeStart must be in yyyy-mm-dd h:i:s format. So, Better to have that format of date picker. If, it's not having, change it to yyyy-mm-dd format by.

$SelectedDate=date("YYYY-mm-dd",strtotime($SelectedDate)); (If not in yyyy-mm-dd format. Otherwise OK)

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblpatientservices WHERE dateTimeStart LIKE '$SelectedDate%' AND status='Done'");
```